# How to show images when the screen is turned-on and the device ready to be unlocked

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how to show images when the screen is turned-on and the device ready to be unlocked. I want to show an image when the screen is turned on. If you have any idea of how to do this...

Comment: Please show me your efforts what have you done to achieve this. check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is searching in the whole Github public repos a good response ? 